# Promoting header values from a file to job execution context

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have a file where the first line contains the field names as headers as below:

```
Id;ToyName;ToyType;ToyColor
1;abc;abc;red
2;pqr;pqr;blue
3;xyz;xyz;orange
```

My reader is as below:

```
<beans:bean id="MyFileItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader" scope="step">
<beans:property name="linesToSkip" value="1"/>
<beans:property name="skippedLinesCallback" ref="headerSkipCallback" />
<beans:property name="resource" ref="MyInputFileResource" />
<beans:property name="lineMapper">
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
                <beans:property name="lineTokenizer">
                    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
                            <beans:property name="delimiter" value=";"/>
                            <beans:property name="names" value="#{jobExecutionContext['columnsFromFileHeader']}" />
                    </beans:bean>
                </beans:property>
                <beans:property name="fieldSetMapper">
                    <beans:bean class="mypackage.MyFieldSetMapper">
                    </beans:bean>
                </beans:property> 
            </beans:bean>
    </beans:property> 
</beans:bean>
```

Thus I have a header line call back implemented to read the skipped header line.

```
<beans:bean id="headerSkipCallback" class="mypackage.HeaderLineHandler" scope="step">
</beans:bean>
```

and the class as:

```
public class HeaderLineHandler implements LineCallbackHandler {
  public void handleLine(final String headerLine) { 
           System.out.println(headerLine);
}}
```

This works correctly and the header line from the file gets printed.

Now I want to use these field names from file header in the `names` property of `DefaultLineTokenizer`

So to put the header line inside the context, I implemented a context injector class as below:

```
public class StepExecutionListenerCtxInjector {

    private ExecutionContext stepExecutionCtx;
    private ExecutionContext jobExecutionCtx;

    @BeforeStep
    public void beforeStep(final StepExecution stepExecution) {
        this.stepExecutionCtx = stepExecution.getExecutionContext();
        this.jobExecutionCtx = stepExecution.getJobExecution().getExecutionContext();
    }


    public ExecutionContext getStepExecutionCtx() {
        return this.stepExecutionCtx;
    }

    public ExecutionContext getJobExecutionCtx() {
        return this.jobExecutionCtx;
    }
}
```

And changed my header line handler to:

```
<beans:bean id="headerSkipCallback" class="mypackage.HeaderLineHandler" scope="step">
    <beans:property name="stepExecutionListener" ref="stepExecutionListener" />
</beans:bean>
```

and the class as:

```
public class HeaderLineHandler implements LineCallbackHandler {

private StepExecutionListenerCtxInjector stepExecutionListener;
public void handleLine(final String headerLine) {

           this.stepExecutionListener.getJobExecutionCtx().put("columnsFromFileHeader", headerLine.replaceAll(";", ","));
}

// getter setters
}
```

Here I am saving the header line as `columnsFromFile` key inside the job execution context.

However, when I am trying to access it in `DefaultLineTokenizer` as:

```
<beans:property name="names" value="#{jobExecutionContext['columnsFromFileHeader']}" />
```

I am getting null pointer exception:

```
org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileParseException: Parsing error at line: 2 in resource=[file [C:\myFile.dat]], input=[1;abc;abc;red]
at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader.doRead(FlatFileItemReader.java:182)

Caused by: 
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.AbstractLineTokenizer.tokenize(AbstractLineTokenizer.java:113)
```

How can I use the header line from the file in the property to `DefaultLineTokenizer`?

Comment: @LucaBassoRicci: Can you please elaborate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `DelimitedLineTokenizer` a non-anonymous bean and inject it into your `HeaderLineHandler`; in `HeaderLineHandler.handleLine()` set `DelimitedLineTokenizer.names` using `handleLine()` input param.
I can't test it but should works.